# how can use a NSDictionary data type in label text?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"User" ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
tableName = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
tableSurname = [dict objectForKey:@"surname"];

self.lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tableName];;
NSLog(@"%@",tableName);
```

NSLog works but in label "( " a parenthesis appears only..

Comment: What is the expected content of the label? Could the parenthesis be the beginning of `(null)`?

Comment: there is one user. (string)name:gokben (string)surname:xxxxx  NSLog prints "(               gokben               )" label text is "("

Comment: Are you sure the `UILabel` is not simply too short?

Comment: :) yes i have tried, but still problem is continue

Comment: Where is this code? Is it in `viewDidLoad`? Also, did you make sure the `IBOutlet` between `self.lbl` and your label is correctly set up?

Comment: No, in a button "touch up inside" button action.  i couldn't manage plist file. I want to use NSUserDefaults to load and read data. i have one user in my app. it has name, surname and photo(image) to be saved. is it a true approach you think? Otherwise should i use core data or plist?

Answer (score 0):

this is my new code- it is running:

```
NSString *saveName = self.txt_name.text;
NSString *saveSurname = self.txt_surname.text;

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:saveName forKey:@"savedName"];
[defaults setObject:saveSurname forKey:@"savedSurname"];
[defaults synchronize];

NSString *loadString = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedName"];

[self.lbl setText:loadString];
```

Comment: That looks an awful lot like [waving a dead chicken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waving_a_dead_chicken_(over_it)) over your problem.